# Terraform create pem file

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, key-pair

I'm new to *Terraform* and I'm trying to create a simple *AWS* *Terraform* code.

It works well but I can see `ec2` and security group, `eip`.

I want to access instance but I don't have `.pem` file.

So it's hard to connect to the `ec2` instance.

How to get the `.pem` file?

can anyone let me know please?

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "alone_ec2" {
  key_name   = "alone_ec2"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}


resource "aws_security_group" "alone_web" {
  name        = "Alone EC2 Security Group"
  description = "Alone EC2 Security Group"
  ingress {
    from_port = 22                                           
    to_port = 22                                             
    protocol = "tcp"                                         
    cidr_blocks = ["${chomp(data.http.myip.body)}/32"]       
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = 8080
    to_port = 8080
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port = 443
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

# EC2
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "ami-02de72c5dc79358c9"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = aws_key_pair.alone_ec2.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.alone_web.id
  ]
  tags = {
    Name                = "example-webservice"
  }
  root_block_device {
    volume_size         = 30 
  }
}

# EIP
resource "aws_eip" "elasticip" {
  instance = aws_instance.web.id
}

output "EIP" {
  value = aws_eip.elasticip.public_ip
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "tls_private_key" to create the key pair, save it to your machine using a provisioner when uploading it to aws.

```
resource "tls_private_key" "this" {
  algorithm     = "RSA"
  rsa_bits      = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "this" {
  key_name      = "my-key"
  public_key    = tls_private_key.this.public_key_openssh

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      echo "${tls_private_key.this.private_key_pem}" > my-key.pem
    EOT
  }
}
```

Comment: does this code mean that my public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub") is not used?

i mean i don't know how it works..

it seems like creating new key. if i use this code, ssh-key generating is not nessasary?
Do i keep developing without knowing the public key?

Comment: In this case you are creating a key pair on execution.

If you want to have the pub part you can do it.
You can save the public key for both openssh and pem formats.
`echo "${tls_private_key.this.public_key_pem}" > ${local.public_key_name}` and 
`echo "${tls_private_key.this.public_key_openssh}" > ${local.public_openssh_name}`

The official documentation for the resource can be found at:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key

Comment: thank you to let me know!!! now i'm understand!